connection.on is not a function
i get the error , i dont understand, it works for normal queries, but for procedures, i get this error

TypeError: connection.on is not a function
at D:\project_digital\backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:792:20
at D:\project_digital\backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\connection-pool.js:371:41
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:447:9)

Relevant codes:

import sql from 'mssql/msnodesqlv8.js'; 

const config = {
  server: 'DESKTOP-5FI8O0F\\SQLEXPRESS', 
  database: 'logs',
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true,
  },
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
};

async function connectToDatabase() {
  try {
    console.log('Attempting to connect to SQL Server...');
    const pool = await sql.connect(config);
    console.log('Connected to SQL Server');
    return pool;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Database connection failed:', error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}
connectToDatabase()

export { connectToDatabase };

app.get('/model_size_shift_counts1', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pool = await connectToDatabase();
    const request = pool.request();
    
    
    const result = await request.execute(`GetModelSizeShiftCountsBetweenDates1`);

    
    res.json(result.recordset);

    await pool.close();

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

The stored pocedure:
USE [cpo_logs]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetModelSizeShiftCountsBetweenDates1]    Script Date: 07-05-2024 08:35:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetModelSizeShiftCountsBetweenDates1]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    
        -- Fetch data for a single date if only one date is provided
        SELECT 
            model,
            size,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Shift = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_shift_a,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Shift = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_shift_b,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Shift = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_shift_c
        FROM 
            [cpo_logs].[dbo].[Prod_log_sheet_line_1]
        GROUP BY 
            model, 
            size;
END;

I don't understand the problem here, please help

"I don't understand the problem here, please help"

Are you sure all "Relevant code" is in the question? What does this do GetModelSizeShiftCountsBetweenDates1 ?

its a stored procedure, in MSSQL , the connection works fine for normal queries, but it is facing errors for procedures,

Seems related: Microsoft / Contributors Node V8 Driver for Node.js for SQL Server Note: If you use import into your lib to prepare your request (const { VarChar } = require('mssql')) you also need to upgrade all your types import into your code (const { VarChar } = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')) or a connection.on is not a function error will be thrown.
